# Not receiving response from Twilio.ListMessages after publishing to IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twilio

I am trying to use the following code to get the message status information from Twilio.

```
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
var request = new MessageListRequest();
var messages = twilio.ListMessages(request);
foreach (var msg in messages.Messages){//Do something here}
```

I can receive the data when running in debug mode. But after publishing it to local computer in IIS, it stops working. I am getting null reference error. Can anyone give me direction or thought on how to resolve this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy the source code into IIS (instead of the published fileset) and try debugging from there. Could be some permission issue to access any resource.

Comment: You are right! It is the proxy server setting that blocked the twilio requests.